# $24x^7 + 5y^2 = 15$ has no integer solutions, having none $\!\bmod 12$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove $5a^2\equiv k \pmod{12}$, where $k\in \{0,5,8,9\}$. Hence show that the equation $24x^7 + 5y^2 = 15$ has no integer solutions.

My lecturer used a table containing $a$, $a^2$, and $5a^2$ from $1$ to $11$ to which he applied $\pmod{12}$
for ex.

$a=3,a^2=9$, and $5a^2=9$

I didn't really understand what he continued on to do, does anyone have alternative method/proof?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's a typo or you copied the problem incorrectly.  You mention mod $12$ below and it looks like it should be the same above.  A square should be equivalent to $0$ or $1$ mod $3$ and $4$, which (when multiplied by 5) is what that set seems to represent.  Also, when you take your equation and consider the equivalence mod $12$, the first term now drops out leaving

$$5y^2\equiv3\pmod{12}$$

which is not on your list.

Answer (score 0):

Your lecturer calculated the remainder when $5a^2$ is divided by $12$, for $a=0$ to $11$. Actually we can stop at $6$, since for any $a$ we have $(12-a)^2\equiv a^2\pmod{12}$. (Indeed  we  could stop at $a=3$, since $(6-a)^2\equiv a^2\pmod{12}$.)

So calculating from $0$ to $6$, we find that modulo $12$, $5y^2$  can take on values $0,5,8,9, 8, 5,0$.

Now suppose that  $24x^n+5y^2=15$.  Then, modulo $12$, we have $5y^2\equiv 3$. That is  impossible, since $3$ is not in our list of possible remainders when $5a^2$ is divided by $12$.

**Remark:** It is simpler to work modulo $4$. If $(x,y)$ is a solution of our equation, then $5y^2\equiv 3\pmod{4}$. That cannot happen if $y$ is even. And if $x\equiv \pm 1\pmod{4}$, then $5x^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, contradicting the fact that $5y^2\equiv 3\pmod{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

The squares modulo $\;12\;$ are

$$0^2=\color{red}0\;,\;1^2=\color{red}1\;,\;2^2=\color{red}4\;,\;3^2=\color{red}9\;,\;4^2=\color{red}{4}\;,\;5^2=\color{red}1\;,\;6^2=\color{red}0,\;$$

(why the above are them all?), and from here

$$5a^2=\begin{cases}0\\5\\8\\9\end{cases}\pmod{17}$$

Working now your equation modulo $\;12\;$ we get

$$5y^2=3$$

which, as seen above, has no solution.